# If $N_G(P)\le H$ then $H=N_G(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> If $G$ is a group, $P$ is a Sylow subgroup of $G$ and $N_G(P)\le H\le G$ then $H=N_G(H)$.

I solved this in case $G$ is finite:

$P$ is also a Sylow subgroup of $H$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(H)$. Hence by Frattini's argument we have

$$N_G(H)=N_{N_G(H)}(P)H\le H.$$

Frattini's argument only works for finite groups, though (since it uses Sylow theorems). So this does not work if $G$ is not finite.

Any hints for $G$ infinite?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can construct a counterexample as follows. Let $X = S_3 =\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^2=(xy)^2=1 \rangle$.

Let $H = \times_{i \in {\mathbb N}} X_i$ be the (restricted) direct product of countably many copies of $X$ with $X_i = \langle x_i,y_i \rangle$ and let $p=2$ and $P= \langle y_i : i \in {\mathbb N} \rangle$.

Let $\tau$ be the automorphism of $H$ of order $3$ defined by $\tau:x_i \mapsto x_i$, $y_i \mapsto y_ix_i$ for all $i$, and let $G = H \rtimes \langle \tau \rangle$.

Then $N_G(P) = P < H$, but $H \lhd G$, so $N_G(H) \ne H$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $H\le N_G(H)$ so we only need show the reverse inclusion. Let $x\in N_G(H)$. Then $xPx^{-1}\le xHx^{-1}=H$, so $P$ and $xPx^{-1}$ are $H$-conjugate, i.e. there exists $h\in H$ such that $xPx^{-1}=hPh^{-1}$. Therefore $xh^{-1}\in N_G(P)\le H$, so $x=(xh^{-1})h\in H$.

Note this works for both the finite and infinite cases.

Comment: I think you're using that $P$ and $xPx^{-1}$ have to be conjugates by a Sylow theorem, aren't you?. However I think that Sylow theorem is not valid for inifinite groups. Here it says so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Sylow_theorems_for_infinite_groups (it seems we would need the conjugacy class of some Sylow is finite)